# Bounded solution of differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Let $f: \Bbb R^{+}\to\Bbb R$  be continuous function, such that $ 0 \leq f(t) \leq m $ for every $t$.
Let a solution $g$ of the differential equation $$t^{2}x''+2tx'-2x=f(t) $$ be bounded when
$t\to\infty$ and $t\to0$.
Prove that $- \frac{m}{2} \leq g(t) \leq 0$ for every $t$.

I have found that solutions of this equations are :
$$x(t)= \left(\frac{-1}{3} \int f(t)t^{2}dt +c_{1}\right) \frac {1}{t} +\left( \frac{1}{3} \int f(t) \frac {1}{t} dt +c_{2}\right)t^{2}$$
and I get $c_{1}=c_{2}=0$, but I don't know how to finish.

Comment: The solution to the homogeneous is $$x(t)=\dfrac {c_1}{t^2}+c_2t$$ You should correct the inetgrals too

Comment: Yes, thank you.

Comment: The powers are the wrong way 'round, the terms with constant coefficients should combine to the homogeneous solution.